# 9 patch buttons with image android

Tags: android, user-interface, nine-patch

I have downloaded Google and Facebook 9-patch button files and added them to my app.
It all seemed surprisingly straightforward, as it seemed to work just fine with just setting button background to the 9-patch file and setting some text. Here is the result:

[image: Android version >= 5]

The thing is, when I previewed my app on device with Android 4.0 and 4.4, this is the result:

[image: Android version < 5]

What can be done, to make the buttons in Android 4 look like the ones in Android 5?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the buttons displaying wrong could be that the content area in the 9-patch file is wrong. You could try to open the files with the draw9patch tool, that is describe [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html). Then you can adjust the content area by adding to or removing from the black bars on the right and bottom.

Alternatively you could try adjusting the padding of your buttons

Comment: Well, according to the 9-patch tool, everything should be fine - http://imgur.com/8KDoa03 - content clearly is at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found a solution.

I used style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" to get rid of borders. For some reasons, it overriden the padding for buttons in version 4.

Once I changed it to style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless" everything worked just fine.